# Wires under diodes on a PCB: distancer, radiator, ground return loop, or something else?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I recently watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2GX2TXwAO8) by bigclivedotcom and there's one unusal (at least for me) thing on the PCB he presented. That's a switched power supply for a flat TV panel:

[image]

Under three parallel power diodes, there are four wires, also parallel, both ends connected to ground blob on the underside. Author of the video suggests that these are distancers that are used to make sure the diodes are not touching the PCB, and/or that these also may be a form of heatsinks.

That doesn't sound right to me. Sure, a proper heatsink is not cheap, but these wires won't take much heat off the diode's body, area of "touch" is like, a point. Times four, but still a point. Worst way to transfer heat (am I right here?). It may be a distancer, to prevent the PCB from heating up, or to provide better airflow? Ok, that makes at least some sense, but then, elsewhere I've seen standing diodes that achieve that as well:

[image]
(random unrelated pic from quick google search http://www.lampizator.eu/lampizator/REFERENCES/Philips%20DAC-960/Philips%2520DAC-960%2520CD%2520DAC%2520with%2520TDA1541A%2520DAC.html)

I understand that "standing diodes" may be harder to mount via standard process in a fab, but then, placing wires **beneath** diodes means that the board also had to have a nonstandard process (am I right here?).

I think that since that's a switching power supply, then those wires may be "additional ground path loops that reduce overall noise generated by switched high current flowing through diodes". My initial thought was that the wires are much closer to the diodes than the ground plane, and induction varies with distance, so the net potential difference induced in the wires will be different than on the ground plane, it will be not balanced, and the wires may actually form a loop for flowing/returning current.

Then I noticed that those wires are actually **perpendicular** to how I imagined the flow. Any magnetic field around the diode's conductor, is, well, around, so the wires are in parallel to the magnetic lines. That reduces induction in the wires down to zero (or almost zero). So the possibility of a ground loop forming is not due to the difference of distance between wires/ground and diodes, but rather due to no induction at all in the wires. Does that make any sense?

Can you confirm bigclivedotcom's explanation, my ground-loop hypothesis, or explain what is the actual purpose of those wires under diodes?

Comment: The wires have no electrical function. I think they are a mechanical stand-off/spacer for the diodes. They might improve cooling by allowinng better airflow, but my quess would be, that they prevent the PCB from burning if the diodes should fail or get too hot.

Comment: My guess would be that they serve as a protective ground path barrier between the two leads of each diode.. In the case of an over-voltage/ transient the current would arc over to the ground-connected wires instead of arcing over to the opposite leads of the diodes potentially causing a high voltage on a part of the circuit which was not designed for it.. That they would be standoffs or any other mechanical feature seems very unlikely to me as it seems like a very costly way to achieve that.

Comment: Aaw.. I stumbled upon my own question after a year :D I think Vinzent's idea is reasonable.. I'm still curious if anyone can explain it for sure, or at least, if anyone saw this pattern or trick elsewhere?

Comment: I think I'll make it a tradition to come back here in December :D